# Mocking a state variable in vitest

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I have a React component that has this line of code:

```js
const [ldContext, setLdContext] = useState<LDContext | null>(null);
```

In my code there are a couple different paths that can occur based on the value of `ldContext`. I cannot figure out for the life of me how to mock this value in vitest.

Here's my component

```
'use client';

import { LDContext, LDFlagSet } from 'launchdarkly-js-client-sdk';
import { useLDClient } from 'launchdarkly-react-client-sdk';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import FeatureFlagContext, { FeatureFlagInterface } from '@/components/shared/contexts/FeatureFlagContext';
import { LDUserContextConfig } from '@/lib/launchdarkly';
import CoreContext from '@/components/shared/contexts/CoreContext';

    function withFeatureFlagProvider(WrappedComponent: React.FC) {
  return function WithFeatureFlagProvider(props: Record<string, any>): JSX.Element {
    const [userFeatureFlagsConfigured, setUserFeatureFlagsConfigured] = useState(false);
    const [featureFlags, setFeatureFlags] = useState<LDFlagSet | null>(null);
    const [ldContext, setLdContext] = useState<LDContext | null>(null);
    const [anonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured, setAnonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured] = useState(false);

    const { loading: coreContextLoading, practioner } = useContext(CoreContext);
    const ldClient = useLDClient();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (practioner) {
        setLdContext(LDUserContextConfig(practioner));
      }
    }, [coreContextLoading]);

    let featureFlagContext: FeatureFlagInterface = {
      userFeatureFlagsConfigured: false,
      anonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured: false,
      featureFlags: null,
    };
    if (ldClient) {
      const featureFlags = ldClient.allFlags();
      if (ldContext) {
        const prevContext = ldClient.getContext();
        if (prevContext?.key !== ldContext.key) {
          ldClient.identify(ldContext, undefined, () => {
            setUserFeatureFlagsConfigured(true);
            setAnonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured(false);
            setFeatureFlags(featureFlags);
          });
        }
      }
      if (!ldClient.getContext()?.anonymous) {
        featureFlagContext = {
          userFeatureFlagsConfigured: true,
          anonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured: false,
          featureFlags,
        };
      } else {
        featureFlagContext = {
          userFeatureFlagsConfigured: false,
          anonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured: true,
          featureFlags,
        };
      }
    }

    if (userFeatureFlagsConfigured && !anonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured && featureFlags !== null) {
      featureFlagContext = {
        userFeatureFlagsConfigured,
        anonymousFeatureFlagsConfigured: false,
        featureFlags,
      };
    }

    return (
      <FeatureFlagContext.Provider value={featureFlagContext}>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </FeatureFlagContext.Provider>
    );
  };
}

export default withFeatureFlagProvider;
```

When I do:

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

const wrapper = render(<WrappedComponent />)
```

I can't do `wrapper.ldContext` or `wrapper.getState()`

Comment: `I cannot figure out for the life of me how to mock this value in vitest.` You aren't supposed to mock it. If your component truly owns that state, you're supposed to test putting it in the correct states and asserting the outcomes. Can you show more component code?

Comment: @AdamJenkins how do you set the state though to put it in the correct state?

Just added my code

Comment: I wanna test each possible code flows (whether the ldContext is defined or not)